# I inserted image deferring on my webpages, but Google SpeedTest tells me to consider lazy-loading offscreen and hidden images

Tags: performance, pagespeed

I inserted, to show images on my webpsges, the solution offered by this site
https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html

I modified the IMG calls

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="image1.jpg" alt="image 1">
```

and inserted, at the bottom of the page, the JS code

```
<script>function init() { var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {      imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));}}} window.onload = init; </script>
```

It works ok. However, when using the Google 'PageSpeed Insights' tool, I'm still obtaining the following message:

```
Consider lazy-loading offscreen and hidden images after all critical resources have finished loading to lower time to interactive
```

---

Is the fix I considered a valid "lazy-loading offscreen" solution? I thought it would fix the problem. Are other fixes better solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using lozad.js + polyfill for deferring offscreen images (aka lazy loading). I haven't read the varvy article but someone who had, wrote that the method only defers the load of images til after the `onload` event and so the initial load weight of the page remains the same.

Lozad will not load an image until it's about to get scrolled into viewport.

For `<img>`s use an empty `<svg>` as the initial `src` value where `6 9` in the `viewBox` below defines the relation between width (6) and height (9) => change those values to fit your context. This will make sure there is no reflow in the page layout once the image(s) load.

```
src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 6 9'%3E%3C/svg%3E"
```

Note that lozad.js uses Intersection Observer API that still lacks in browser support so be sure to add a polyfill.

Good luck!